# AddThisEvent and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement addthisevent into my jqm application (1.4), but I have two issues.

1. The Link/Button doesn't appear. Looking with Firebug shows that the css class isn't loaded as hidden.
2. After manually activating the visibility using firebug, the link doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have experience with integrating addthisevent into a jqm app? Is there anything I have to be particularly careful of?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you can create a jsFiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: Hi,

thanks for you fast reply.
I´ve prepared a simple page within my jqm app.

http://www.aicrm.de/addthisevent-demo.html

Also adding rel="external" does not change the behavior. Still confused.
Thanks a lot for you investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the jQM CSS interferes with AddThisEvent CSS.  One solution is to add `data-role="none"` to the link which tells jQM to leave the link alone and not to enhance it.

```
<a href="#" data-role="none" title="Add to Calendar" class="addthisevent" rel="external">
    Add to Calendar
    <span class="_start">10-05-2014 11:38:46</span>
    <span class="_end">11-05-2014 11:38:46</span>
    <span class="_zonecode">38</span>
    <span class="_summary">Summary of the event</span>
    <span class="_description">Description of the event</span>
    <span class="_location">Location of the event</span>
    <span class="_organizer">Organizer</span>
    <span class="_organizer_email">Organizer e-mail</span>
    <span class="_facebook_event">http://www.facebook.com/events/160427380695693</span>
    <span class="_all_day_event">true</span>
    <span class="_date_format">DD/MM/YYYY</span>
</a>
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yBXGR/1/)**

Comment: Exactly. Adding the attributes .. rel="external" data-role="none" .. was the solution. 

Thanks a lot